# Decode from ISO-2022-JP-MS to UTF-8 in PHP - IMAP

Tags: php, imap

I am Using IMAP in order to check some emails( sometimes in Japanese, sometimes in English), and some of them I get the results encrypted in ISO-2022-JP.
I was trying using

```
$msg='=1B$B#77n=1B(B

    =1B$B2V2&=1B(B
    
    =1B$B%K%e!<%9$N$_=1B(B';

$utf8Msg = mb_convert_encoding($msg,'UTF-8','ISO-2022-JP-MS');
```

to decode the message, but it is not working.

Do you guys have any suggestion on how I should proceed to decode any message(Japanese, English and so on) using IMAP? or is there a better way to read email in php? Like some method that already shows the decoded message?

Comment: It looks like you have quoted-printable text there. [Decode it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php) first.

Comment: Ohh right. thanks, I added `$string = quoted_printable_decode ( $string )` and it works. =)